# Optimized .plist/textures for walk animations

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, textures

I am trying to 'squeeze' my textures for walking animations. The anim has 8 frames, but actually can be done quite well with 1-2-3-4-5-4-3-2 which would fit nicely in a 128x128 points texture. Do you know of a tool that can create the plist entries for 6-7-8 that are mapped onto the 4-3-2 areas of the texture ?

Coding is still an option, but was wondering if some tool has that out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised there's still Cocos2D developers out there who aren't using [TexturePacker](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). :)

Check out the **Alias Creation** section under [Features](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/features), I'm quoting (but also can confirm that this works perfectly):

> If two images are identical after trimming only one image is placed in
>   the sprite sheet. The duplicates will just be added to the description
>   file allowing you to access it with both names. 
>   [image]
>
> This is perfect when using animations: You simply don't have to care about equal phases.

Comment: hahaha ... i may be an adequate sw engineer, but i really suck at using it. Thanks for the tip, my artsy friend will receive this info.